In the nvim telescope in the Results field icons are cropped
Font: JetBrainsMono Nerd Font
enter image description here
Nvim version:
NVIM v0.9.5
Build type: Release
LuaJIT 2.1.1719379426

Telescope version: 0.1.8
Telescope.lua:
return {
  'nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim', tag = '0.1.8',
  dependencies = { 'nvim-lua/plenary.nvim' },
  config = function()
    local builtin = require('telescope.builtin')
    vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>ff', builtin.find_files, {})
    vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>fg', builtin.live_grep, {})
  end
}

Expected:
enter image description here

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
